# Getting blank page while using spring boot web application with App Engine Standard (Java 8)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have successfully deployed my spring boot sample web application to App Engine Standard (Java 8). This applications has some jsp pages. But i am getting blank page instead of my orginal page. And also not getting any errors.

**My index page controller is**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showIndexPage(Model model,HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException
    {
        return "index";
    }
```

**index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Welcome</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**application.propertoes**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This is the documentation i have done.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard

[image]

Any suggession?

### EDIT

**But /hello is working fine**

```
@RestController
public class HelloworldController {
  @GetMapping("/hello")
  public String hello() {
    return "Hello world - springboot-appengine-standard!";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being anything close to spring-boot expert, I suspect 2 things:

1: You're using `@RequestMapping` where most examples (some that I just tried) use `@GetMapping` instead. If I'm not mistaken using `@RequestMapping` means you'll need to define `@ResponseBody` as well.

2: To serve static files with GAE you'll need to include that in the `appengine-web.xml` too as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref) under `<static-files>`:

A sample:

```
<static-files>
  <include path="/my_static-files" >
    <http-header name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
                 value="http://example.org" />
  </include>
</static-files>
```

GAE seems to be working fine ans serving requests as expected. It's either your spring-boot config or appengine-web.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply. still i am getting the blank page